# bash: /usr/local/bin/fab: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Tags: python

Fabric is not working for me. I get the following error when I run fabric.

```
fab realm:prod role:tools,1 build
bash: /usr/local/bin/fab: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

It used to work before. But I am not sure what really changed. 
I had run the below commands

```
brew doctor 
brew install git
```

I don't know how those brew commands could mess with my python version

```
$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/python
lrwxr-xr-x  1 vaibhav.chidrewar  admin  68 Nov  8  2014 /usr/local/bin/python -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
$ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
$ which fab
/usr/local/bin/fab
$ head -n1 /usr/local/bin/pip
#!/usr/bin/python

$echo $PATH
/usr/local/lib/cw:/usr/local/bin:/Users/vaibhav.chidrewar/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling pip and fabric. But even after that I get the same error.

```
$ sudo easy_install pip
Searching for pip
Best match: pip 1.5.6
Processing pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg
pip 1.5.6 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2.7 script to /usr/local/bin
Installing pip2 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Users/vaibhav.chidrewar/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.6-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pip
Finished processing dependencies for pip


$ sudo pip install fabric
Downloading/unpacking fabric
  Downloading Fabric-1.12.0-py2-none-any.whl (92kB): 92kB downloaded
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): paramiko>=1.10,<2.0 in ./Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from fabric)
Installing collected packages: fabric
Successfully installed fabric
Cleaning up...
```

After that I tried install Flask and it worked. 
So not sure whats wrong with Fabric.

Comment: It wants `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7`. That may be hardcoded in the script somewhere.

Comment: @Thilo just running 'fab' also gives the same error. fab
bash: /usr/local/bin/fab: /usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: If you run `sudo which pip` is it the pip you expect?

Comment: @kkurian sudo which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that my `.bash_profile` was not getting sourced.
So following was missing.

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:${PATH}"
```

For now I copied the contents of .bash_profile to .bashrc and things are working fine again